# Change appearance of nomenclature title but not in ToC

Tags: fontsize, nomenclature

I am trying to change the header of the nomenclature section. I would like it to be a different font and all upper case. If I rename `\nomname` with

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\MakeUppercase Nomenclature}% etc.
```

it will also appear like this in the ToC, which I explicitly am trying to avoid. Is there an easy/dirty trick of doing this? Similarly, I'd like to do this for a reference section later on.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be achieved by modifying the `thenomenclature` environment; you don't use it directly, but it appears in the `.nls` file produced by MakeIndex.

The simplest way is to do the changes with a patch:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\section*{\nomname}}
  {\section*{\MakeUppercase{\nomname}}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\chapter*{\nomname}}
  {\chapter*{\MakeUppercase{\nomname}}}
  {}{}
```

Other formatting instructions can be added at will. Remember, though, that `\MakeUppercase` wants an argument and is not a declarative command like `\bfseries`.

Comment: This works quite nicely! Thanks! Any ideas how to tackle the same for biblatex/biber based bibliography?

Comment: @Markus The manual of `biblatex` describes `\defbibheading`.